# Error with Vector3 and float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game an object is printed out every few seconds.

But I get an error with my float values. Here is my code:

```
grassBarn.transform.position = new Vector3(43, 12, 0);
```

Errors like this appear

> Assets/scripts/gameplay/Classname.cs(44,62): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments

and sometimes like this

> Assets/scripts/gameplay/Classname.cs(44,62): error CS1503: Argument #2 cannot convert double expression to type float

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? Please provide more information.

Comment: I strongly recommend trying to debug on your own (along with Google's help) before you post on SO. Also, @aribeiro mentioned, it helps to post the error that you receive and also what you've tried to correct it with yourself. All the best!

Comment: surprisingly, perhaps incredibly, I don't think this is a duplicate @andeart - it's the first!

Comment: @JoeBlow That's funnily surprising. I do feel the need to sigh each time something like this shows up on SO.

Comment: What environment do you use for programming? The current compiler of visual studio is compiling it without issues.

Comment: @andeart - don't worry, i click "Close" all day!  :)  Felix ... this is for Unity which uses some shabby version of Mono.  You know, it's true it actually only throws errors in some cases like "13.0" and so on: but it's certainly the case you always need the "f" for floats in the Unity milieu anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vector3 class works with float values.

When programming with C#, you have to use a `f` value and assign to your decimals to tell the compiler that you want them to be a float value.
I suggest using this:

`grassBarn.transform.position = new Vector3(43f, 12f, 0f);`

Comment: Thanks. I understand now! I was a bit tired when I wrote the code lol. 

Comment: a nic canonical answer by JohnGool!

Comment: @MarcDavidson - don't program tired. If you're tired, just stop. It's not possible to program unless you're in perfect health, have good muscle tone, and get plenty of exercise and fresh air. You have to eat a low-carb diet - so-called "primal" approach to diet is ideal - to program computers. Programming is easily the most difficult mental exercise humans have ever done, so you need total whole-body health to do it.

Comment: I agree with @JoeBlow. Never program tired. I have done it in the past and it never pays off.